# I am converting wmv to mp4 file using ffmpeg but it doesn't play on html5 video tag

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am using version of ffmpeg 1.2.3 in php . It successfully converts the video to mp4 which i can play using flv player but when i add this video to html5 video tag it doest work properly.

The Command is

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/vid/upload/inputfile.wmv -s 500x400 -strict -2  /var/www/html/vid/mp4videos/outputfile.mp4 2>&1");
```

HTML CODE

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls><source src="mp4videos/outputfile.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: You need to include the complete ffmpeg console output with your ffmpeg command. Otherwise we waste time guessing. What browsers does it work or not work in?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `-vcodec libx264` (to use H264 video format) in command line.

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/vid/upload/inputfile.wmv -s 500x400 -vcodec libx264 -strict -2  /var/www/html/vid/mp4videos/outputfile.mp4
```

The HTML5 video does not read every video format.

[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support).

Comment: Can you post the link of your video, please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/vid/upload/inputfile.wmv -f mp4 -s 500x400 -strict -2  /var/www/html/vid/mp4videos/outputfile.mp4 2>&1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
 exec("ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/html/vid/upload/inputfile.wmv -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags faststart -hide_banner /var/www/html/vid/mp4videos/outputfile.mp4");
```

The `faststart` option is very important.